# Chrome continued to increase memory used and eventually crash after a loop refresh

Tags: php, jquery, memory, browser, crash

I have an auto refresh for updating data after a countdown sec and the task manager of chrome shows that the used memory will be increased(the increased amount depends on content of page) and I guess this is the root cause for the crash issue.

I have tried Firefox and it better than chrome (crash issue is not always happen but not solved this issue).

my content of page is through php and use some jQuery to control the view's element.

I have no idea where can I begin for this problem (the usage of javascript or ?),

Any suggestion or experience will be appreciated!

=========

Below function will be fired after a specific countdown sec for updating data and inject into the  tag

```
function update_game_info_page(){
    if (sec === 0) {
         $.ajax({
            url: '/mgt/main/ajax_game_info_page',
            type:"GET",
            dataType:'text',

            success: function( data ) {

              $("#game_info").html( data );

            }

        });
        clearInterval(countdown);

    }
    sec--;
}
```

=======

My target is have a page like

http://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/#/odds/nba/game/pointspread.html

and this page is continue updating data without any increasing memory ,
I'd like to know how to do (php give a json data object for jquery and jquery show the content of html?) , any example will be also appreciated!

Comment: Without your code, it's hard to say where does your problem come from. (Probably not PHP though)

Comment: @ClémentMalet it is easy enough to make a loop in php that will crash your browser

Comment: @SuperDJ That's where the word 'Probably' comes into effect. ;)